# Where does WPF perform matrix operations?

Tags: wpf, gpu

I am wondering that if I use a WPF application on a system which has a GPU, does it do matric operation on the GPU?

My first guess is no, but I saw that it is very fast when for example we are doing 3D projection and I am sure that it is doing its projection on GPU.

How can I find which method is running on GPU and which one is taking place on CPU?

Comment: Matrices are used in a lot of places (some will go to the GPU, and some to the CPU), can you be more specific about what matrix operation you are talking about here?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Which one is running in GPU and which one on cpu? For example 2D and 3D transform matrix operations? Are they run on CPU or GPU?